# What feedback message should be appropriate in this case?

Tags: feedback, notification, prompt, messagebox

I am creating a time reporting tool. Users will use this web app to enter and record the time they spend on an activity (task). Users can add time in hh:mm format. Users can also enter values in decimal, which will be converted into hh:mm format by the system.
For example: when user enters 3.5, it converts into 3:30. or 3.25 into 3:15 or 3.10 into 3:06
This conversion is done by the system. For the user to notice these changes made by the system, I want to add a feedback message. I am not sure what kind of feedback message would make sense.
Please refer to attached images.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: "Decimal time converted into 60 minute time" ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a very bad idea: what happens if I want to add 3 hours and 25 minutes? or if I actually do enter the time in hours and minutes - If I enter 3.30 will it register 3.5 hours or 3 hours and 18 minutes?

**Set the format you want users to enter their times with and keep it that way**: If you're asking users to enter decimal time then you should display decimal time. If you're asking them to add hours and minutes then display hours and minutes. Switching between the two is only going to cause confusion and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

I have a question here: Will the user be entering **all the values at a time** or he will enter **one-two values at a time**?

The answer to above question will make huge difference.

If the user will be entering all the values at once, it is not advisable to show the feedback message upon every entry as it will irritate user by continuously showing the feedback message. In this case, it will be better to show the message at the top in prominent way so that user can see it and understand it.

Now if user will enter only couple entries at a time, it is OK to show the feedback message when he goes into next cell (by clicking or pressing TAB) as it will make clear for him about the conversion system is making.

Let me know if this helps!